# Add text in TinyMce on position of the cursor, onClick on icon

Tags: javascript, tinymce

How to add text in tinyMce in the position of the cursor, when one of the icons will be clicked? The icon has id = sInput_netadvimage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
function insertYourContent(){
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, "Whatever text");
}

var myIcon = document.getElementById("sInput_netadvimage");
if(myIcon.attachEvent)
    myIcon.attachEvent("onclick", insertYourContent);
else if(myIcon.addEventListener)
    myIcon.addEventListener("click", insertYourContent, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function insertYourContent(text){
        tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand("elm1","mceInsertContent",false,text);
}
```